# In connecting to an access point, Win and Mac are ok but linux not

Tags: wifi

We have a wireless network which has WPA enterprise security. Its authentication is by Protected EAP and inner authentication is on MSCHAPv2.

All devices with a wireless interface can connect to this access point with their username and password. All devices has windows or mac and the setting are auto detected by their network manager. But there a device which has Linux mint 12 on it, and it can not connect to AP. actually it once connected but had been disconnected after two minutes!

What's the difference and how can we troubleshoot this problem?
Is it something we can do on AP or some setting on that linux device?

Comment: When we restart the wireless lan interface on that linux machine, we are able to connect to AP and it works fine! But I still don't know the reason!